# how to add header and payload info in python http.client methods

Tags: python, put, http.client

Need help for http.client library for doing a PUT request, like to know if there is a way to add header info and payload in the PUT request, 
I see documentation says as below, is there a way to embed header and payload info in the BODY? If so, could you please show an example.

```
import http.client

BODY = "***filecontents***"
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost", 8080)
conn.request("PUT", "/file", BODY)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add header info as a dict on 4 arguments. As far as know is not possible embed in the BODY.

```
import http.client
BODY = "***filecontents***"
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1", 5000)
conn.connect()
conn.request("PUT", "/file", BODY, {"someheadername":"someheadervalues",                  
"someotherheadername":"someotherheadervalues"})
```

Comment: Thanks rouland for your answer, i was getting 500 internal error due to my mistake in payload content, thanks for your answer that conn.request is overloaded  with extram params for payload and headers

Answer (score 2):

The command:

```
conn.request("PUT", "/file", BODY)
```

Is overloaded as below as well, so its pretty straight forward :)

```
conn.request("PUT", "url", payload, headers)
```